# Shortest distance algorithm Python

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I wanted to create a simple breadth first search algorithm, which returns the shortest path.

An actor information dictionary maps and actor to the list of movies the actor appears in:

```
actor_info = { "act1" : ["movieC", "movieA"], "act2" : ["movieA", "movieB"], 
     "act3" :["movieA", "movieB"], "act4" : ["movieC", "movieD"], 
     "act5" : ["movieD", "movieB"], "act6" : ["movieE"], 
     "act7" : ["movieG", "movieE"], "act8" : ["movieD", "movieF"], 
     "KevinBacon" : ["movieF"], "act10" : ["movieG"], "act11" : ["movieG"] }
```

The inverse of this maps movies to the list of actors appearing in them:

```
movie_info = {'movieB': ['act2', 'act3', 'act5'], 'movieC': ['act1', 'act4'], 
      'movieA': ['act1', 'act2', 'act3'], 'movieF': ['KevinBacon', 'act8'], 
      'movieG': ['act7', 'act10', 'act11'], 'movieD': ['act8', 'act4', 'act5'], 
      'movieE': ['act6', 'act7']}
```

so for a call

```
shortest_dictance("act1", "Kevin Bacon", actor_info, movie_info)
```

I should get `3` since `act1` appears in `movieC` with `Act4` who appears in `movieD` with `Act8` who appears in `movie F` with `KevinBacon`. So the shortest distance is 3.

So far I have this:

```
def shotest_distance(actA, actB, actor_info, movie_info):
   '''Return the number of movies required to connect actA and actB. 
   If theres no connection return -1.'''

    # So we keep 2 lists of actors:
    #   1.The actors that we have already investigated.
    #   2.The actors that need to be investigated because we have found a 
    #      connection beginning at actA. This list must be 
    #      ordered, since we want to investigate actors in the order we 
    #      discover them.
    #      -- Each time we put an actor in this list, we also store
    #         her distance from actA.
    investigated = []
    to_investigate = [actA]
    distance = 0
    while actB not in to_investigate and to_investigate!= []:
        for actor in to_investigate:
            to_investigated.remove(actA)
            investigated.append(act)

            for movie in actor_info[actor]:
                for co_star in movie_info[movie]:
                    if co_star not in (investigated and to_investigate):
                        to_investigate.append(co_star)

 ....
 ....

 return d
```

I can't figure the appropriate way to keep track of the distances discovered each of iteration of the code. Also the code seems to be very ineffecient time wise.

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly create one graph out of this to connect all the nodes and then run the shortest_path code(There could be an efficient graph library to do this instead of the function mentioned below, nevertheless this one is elegant) and then find out all the number of movie names from the shortest path.

```
for i in movie_info:
    actor_info[i] = movie_info[i]

def find_shortest_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
    path = path + [start]
    if start == end:
        return path
    if not start in graph:
        return None
    shortest = None
    for node in graph[start]:
        if node not in path:
            newpath = find_shortest_path(graph, node, end, path)
            if newpath:
                if not shortest or len(newpath) < len(shortest):
                    shortest = newpath
    return shortest

L = find_shortest_path(actor_info, 'act1', 'act2')
print len([i for i in L if i in movie_info])
```

find_shortest_path Source: http://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

Comment: Coding nit:  use ``start in graph`` rather than ``graph.has_key(start)``.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it works. It keeps track of a current set of movies. For each step, it looks at all of the one-step-away movies which haven't already been considered ("seen").

```
actor_info = { "act1" : ["movieC", "movieA"], "act2" : ["movieA", "movieB"], 
     "act3" :["movieA", "movieB"], "act4" : ["movieC", "movieD"], 
     "act5" : ["movieD", "movieB"], "act6" : ["movieE"], 
     "act7" : ["movieG", "movieE"], "act8" : ["movieD", "movieF"], 
     "KevinBacon" : ["movieF"], "act10" : ["movieG"], "act11" : ["movieG"] }

movie_info = {'movieB': ['act2', 'act3', 'act5'], 'movieC': ['act1', 'act4'], 
      'movieA': ['act1', 'act2', 'act3'], 'movieF': ['KevinBacon', 'act8'], 
      'movieG': ['act7', 'act10', 'act11'], 'movieD': ['act8', 'act4', 'act5'], 
      'movieE': ['act6', 'act7']}

def shortest_distance(actA, actB, actor_info, movie_info):
    if actA not in actor_info:
        return -1  # "infinity"
    if actB not in actor_info:
        return -1  # "infinity"
    if actA == actB:
        return 0

    dist = 1
    movies = set(actor_info[actA])
    end_movies = set(actor_info[actB])
    if movies & end_movies:
        return dist

    seen = movies.copy()
    print "All movies with", actA, seen
    while 1:
        dist += 1
        next_step = set()
        for movie in movies:
            for actor in movie_info[movie]:
                next_step.update(actor_info[actor])
        print "Movies with actors from those movies", next_step
        movies = next_step - seen 
        print "New movies with actors from those movies", movies
        if not movies:
            return -1 # "Infinity"

        # Has actorB been in any of those movies?
        if movies & end_movies:
            return dist

        # Update the set of seen movies, so I don't visit them again
        seen.update(movies)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print shortest_distance("act1", "KevinBacon", actor_info, movie_info)
```

The output is

```
All movies with act1 set(['movieC', 'movieA'])
Movies with actors from those movies set(['movieB', 'movieC', 'movieA', 'movieD'])
New movies with actors from those movies set(['movieB', 'movieD'])
Movies with actors from those movies set(['movieB', 'movieC', 'movieA', 'movieF', 'movieD'])
New movies with actors from those movies set(['movieF'])
3
```

Here's a version which returns a list of movies making up the minimum connection (None for no connection, and an empty list if the actA and actB are the same.)

```
def connect(links, movie):
    chain = []
    while movie is not None:
        chain.append(movie)
        movie = links[movie]
    return chain

def shortest_distance(actA, actB, actor_info, movie_info):
    if actA not in actor_info:
        return None  # "infinity"
    if actB not in actor_info:
        return None  # "infinity"
    if actA == actB:
        return []

    # {x: y} means that x is one link outwards from y
    links = {}

    # Start from the destination and work backward
    for movie in actor_info[actB]:
        links[movie] = None
    dist = 1
    movies = links.keys()

    while 1:
        new_movies = []
        for movie in movies:
            for actor in movie_info[movie]:
                if actor == actA:
                    return connect(links, movie)
                for other_movie in actor_info[actor]:
                    if other_movie not in links:
                        links[other_movie] = movie
                        new_movies.append(other_movie)
        if not new_movies:
            return None # Infinity
        movies = new_movies

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dist = shortest_distance("act1", "KevinBacon", actor_info, movie_info)
    if dist is None:
        print "Not connected"
    else:
        print "The Kevin Bacon Number for act1 is", len(dist)
        print "Movies are:", ", ".join(dist)
```

Here's the output:

```
The Kevin Bacon Number for act1 is 3
Movies are: movieC, movieD, movieF
```